# How to use the Box-Tidwell function with a logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I get errors using the boxTidwell function from the 'car' package for a logistic regression model.

I want to model

fatalCancer ~ globy1, where fatalCancer is a factor with two levels and globy1 is numeric (all positive). I am testing this to check the assumption of linearity of globy1 with the logit of the outcome.

Looking at the error messages (below) and the boxTidwell function code, it seems that maybe there's a problem with fatalCancer being a factor. There isn't anything in the boxTidwell documentation about specifying that it's a logistic model. In the example in Section 6.4 of Fox's _An R Companion to Applied Regression (p.312) the example logistic regression didn't require any specification.

Is there a way to fix the syntax of the boxTidwell function below?

```
> library(car)
Loading required package: carData
> 
> load("m2dat.RData")
> m2dat <- na.omit(m2dat)
> dim(m2dat) 
[1] 116   3    
> head(m2dat)
   dog globy1 fatalCancer
1 101A    3.1          No
2 102A    2.9          No
3 103A    4.9          No
4 104A    3.1         Yes     
5 105A    2.8         Yes
6 106A    3.5          No
> boxTidwell(fatalCancer ~ globy1, data=m2dat)
 MLE of lambda Score Statistic (z) Pr(>|z|)    
        6.5694                  NA       NA

iterations =  21      
There were 48 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()    
Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
3: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
4: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
5: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
6: In Ops.factor(r, 2) : ‘^’ not meaningful for factors
7: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
8: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors    
9: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
10: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
...
46: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors 
47: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
48: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

The score statistic ends up NA, and I would like to run the test successfully.

Comment: Nothing in the documentation at `?boxTidwell` suggests that it would work for anything other than a regular `lm`.

Answer (score 2):

The linearity assumption for logistic regression is between the log-odds and the predictor variables, not between the outcome and predictor variables (as you have entered them into the function).

```
lreg <- glm(fatalCancer ~ globy1, data=m2dat, family = binomial(link="logit"))
logodds <- lreg$linear.predictors
boxTidwell(logodds ~ globy1)
```

Alternatively, this is something you can assess with a scatter plot:

```
plot(logodds ~ globy1)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: if you use a boxtidwell, the response should be a log odds ratio.. However I am not so sure about passing the log-odds predictions from a fit to the boxTidwell to find a suitable transformation because this is already a prediction from a linear fit. Maybe passing the residuals, but again, not very clear what the OP wants..

Comment: Just a comment, not criticism.. i am not very sure myself

Comment: I don't disagree with you... after I posted the answer I started second-guessing it. My answer should solve the warnings but I'm not sure it is statistically valid. The alternative is to run a logistic regression with the interaction term of the predictor and it's log, i.e., fatalCancer ~ globy1 * log(globy1). The summary function will show you any violations. This tests the linearity assumption according to Hosmer and Lemeshow (1989).

Comment: This won't work because the argument is circular.  In this example, logodds is globy1 times it's estimated coefficient.  By definition of how its calculated the relationship is linear.  If you look at the plot you suggested, it will be perfectly straight line (regardless of the data) for the same reason.

Comment: According to John Fox, the creator of the `car` package, the Box Tidwell test is not appropriate for logistic regression, only linear regression. He recommends using the `crPlots` function for evaluating the linearity assumption.